# MySQL calculate ratios from group-by query result

Tags: mysql, group-by

**ADD:**

SQL query:

```
SELECT s.name
     , d.feeling
     , COUNT(1) AS times 
  FROM data_table d
     , staff s 
 WHERE d.nid = s.id 
   AND d.project_id = 1 
   AND d.crawl_time BETWEEN '2018-10-17' AND '2018-10-24' 
   AND LENGTH(TRIM(d.feeling)) > 0 
 GROUP 
    BY d.nid
     , d.feeling
```

**ADD (END)**

I write a sql to query the times of each body's feelings group by name and feeling. Here is the result.

```
-- a certain sql returns, not an existing table --    
`name`  `feeling`   `times`  (expect)
Jack     happy        10       0.45
Jack     sad          7        0.31
Jack     common       5        0.22
Lily     happy        3        0.27
Lily     sad          6        0.54
Lily     common       2        0.18
Sam      happy        6        0.42
Sam      sad          7        0.5
Sam      common       1        0.07
```

Now the aim is to calculate the ratio of everyone's feelings. For example, the happy feeling of Jack takes `10/(10+7+5)` of his feelings, and for sad feeling is `7/(10+7+5)`.
When using `SUM(result.count)` and `GROUP BY name` to figure, the sad or common feelings cannot show. Then I use subquery, but the table does not exist. Is there anyway to work without creating a view?

Comment: Can you include your query too?

Comment: Can you include your query too?

Comment: I put the query on the top.

Comment: I editted the post and omitted the informal words. Sorry for the impropriety. @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

One solution which should work on any version of MySQL uses a subquery to find the sum of `times` for each name, and then joins to it:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t1.feeling,
    t1.times,
    t1.times / t2.times_sum AS feeling_ratio
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, SUM(times) AS times_sum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, and have access to analytic functions, then there is simpler way of writing this:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t1.feeling,
    t1.times,
    t1.times / SUM(t1.times) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.name) AS feeling_ratio
FROM yourTable t1;
```

Comment: Im afraid the yourTable you mentioned does not exist, it's a view(query result), not a table.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  Just replace `yourTable` with `yourView` and then query should still work.

Comment: execuse me, do you mean I should replace twice?  Just now I tried and replaced the first t1 but did not replace the second. It went wrong: table t1 doesn't exist. @Tim Biegeleisen